# Moving f6 pawn in Max Lange Attack

Tags: opening, analysis, italian-game

In the position at 14:28 of [this](https://youtu.be/DMcDNVSXyd0) video, why can't black just make the move f6? I wish to know as it was stated in the video that black will lose the other rook.

```
[FEN "2k3r1/ppp1qpPp/2n1b3/2b3B1/2ppN1P1/8/PPP2P1P/R2QR1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `f6` White takes with the bishop and Black loses a piece (bishop on `c5` since `d6` square is attacked by the white knight and `f8` is attacked by the white pawn; no other piece is protecting the bishop).

Comment: Should add, that after Qf7, Nxc5, Qxf6 white wins the Be6 which is twice attacked.